# How to plot in spyder3 via matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib, plot, histogram, spyder, plottable

In the beginning I was able to view the plot in the upper right window of Spyder3 (variable explorer)
But now nothing is being plottet anymore (no errors)

I wonder if theres something wrong with my code:

```
%matplotlib inline 
plt.rcParams.update({'figure.figsize':(7,5), 'figure.dpi':100})
plt.hist(raveledHighs, bins=1)
plt.gca().set(title='Frequency Histogram', ylabel='Frequency in crvslong'); 
plt.show()
```

Otherwise what can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

found out that the box for the plot section was actually unclicked:

```
View -> panes -> plot
```

Hope it helps any of you in the future